# Delphi 2010: group items of a TListview

Tags: delphi, listview, grouping, listitem

I'm working on a project of mine (for my personal use only) to create something like a "**MediaStore**" to manage my media files (DVDs & CDs content ) in a MySQL database.

(See the next image to preview my application)

[image: Preview of my application]

But the problem is that I wand to group each subFolder in grouped listItems (as the exmpale shown below) ...and I'm not sure if it's possible in delphi or not (using a listview or any other component).

[image: What my application listview should be like]

**So is it possible in delphi to realize this goal?**

And thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: 'i.e.' and 'e.g.' do not mean the same thing!

Comment: Anyhow, of course *anything* is possible in Delphi (or any other language). If something is possible in one native Win32 language, it is in any other...

Comment: I would suggest you my personal favorite component, [`Virtual Treeview`](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview).

Comment: @Andreas: yes it should be 'e.g'.

Comment: @TLama: I'll try the [Virtual Treeview](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) `component`

Comment: That's hardly a list view. It's a tree structure.

Comment: Or you might give a try to the [`Mustangpeak VirtualShellTools`](https://code.google.com/p/mustangpeakvirtualshelltools/) as it seems you want to have some sort of Explorer like tree view. It's based on Virtual Treeview control and might save you a lot of work.

Comment: [Virtual Treeview](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) is exactly what I was looking for..thanks TLama & everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: Above links are broken. There is the new link to VirtualTreeView: https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView